# Android Add/Remove File Directory

Tags: android

I'm creating an App where I will import files the app will use, then remove and replace them with new ones when available. What folder should those be stored in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android dev documentation have a page about how to handle files: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Maybe you should take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the user will get the files for the app, and the type of files you are talking about.
If for example the app is going to download the files from a server for the user, and the files are of a type that are only going to be used by your app, then either the Internal Private or External Private storage are probably best. If the file type is something that other apps will also use, then one of the appropriate External Public directories is best (for example Music, Pictures, Movies, Downloads etc).

Comment: I want them to be able to either download it from an email or website or insert it from an external sd card.